# Callbacks / Events in C#

Tags: c#, events, callback, xmpp

Iv'e pretty new to C# ATM and I seem to be having trouble with Jabber-Net

Im trying to create a basic chat application that will connect users via Jaber Services, the issues im having are with the Callbacks.

The main error I seem to get is about the "Event required but used like 'type'", or something along those lines..

Im at work atm so i cant give you full details but it seems to be when i try adding callbacks.. For example:

```
JabberClient Jabber = new JabberCLient();
Jabbaer.OnConnect += new jabber.connection.XmppStream.OnConnect(Some_event_function);
```

Now this code was just of the top of my head and may be wrong, i work by fixing errors as I'm learning but I get an error that basically telling me that **what im doing should be done as an event but im using as a type**

Can anybody shed some light on the matter please.

Regards Robert Pitt

Comment: It works much better if you post from a place where you _do_ have the actual code.

Comment: Yes I will update the OP As soon as I can, But its not just about the code, I do need to understand events in general. I am sorry for the problem thou.

Comment: You seem to be mixing your layers - ATM is layer 2, XMPP is layer 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, the line

```
  Jabbaer.OnConnect += new 
      jabber.connection.XmppStream.OnConnect(Some_event_function);
```

is wrong because XmppStream.OnConnect is a property and you need a delegate definition at that point. But instead of debugging what came from your memory, just use the shorthand form:

```
  Jabbaer.OnConnect += Some_event_function;
```

Comment: I will give that a try, I'm not sure why I was using the ` jabber.connection.XmppStream.OnConnect`, I'm sure somewhere I was told to. i will let you know soon the results.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second line with:

```
Jabber.OnConnect += Some_event_function;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I cant test right now will do later, but i am sure I have attempted that method and got errors, I'm not 100% sure thou.

Comment: If you got error, that's probably caused by signature difference (between the event and the callback).

Comment: I don't think so, it should be compile error (caught at compile time). If you're referring to runtime error (.NET Exception), then something is wrong inside the function.